# Get the picker value when another button is pushed

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

This is my index.xml

index.xml

```
        <Window>
            <Picker id="picker" type="Ti.UI.PICKER_TYPE_DATE" selectionIndicator="true" top="100"></Picker>
            <Button id="button" onClick="clickSelDateBut" title="決定"
        top="350" width="100" height="50" />
        </Window>
```

I would like to get the picker value when button is clicked

For now my source code is here.

index.js

```
$.picker.addEventListener('change',function(e){
    selDay = e.value.getDate();
    selMonth = e.value.getMonth() + 1;
    selYear = e.value.getFullYear();
});// keep the data when 'change' event happens..

function clickSelDateBut(e){
//using selDay selMonth selYear here

}
```

However,it's not cool.

I think I should pick up the data from picker when the button is clicked.

How can I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u want some button to be clicked and get its value then do something like this

```
$.button.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    selDay = picker.value.getDate();
    selMonth = picker.value.getMonth() + 1;
    selYear = picker.value.getFullYear(); });
})
```